# Browser is intermittently showing JSON when I do not want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following jQuery function. I do not want to display the JSON data that is returned.  I just want my dialog box to show a message to the user. What is strange is that sometimes I get a dialog message as desired and sometimes I get a page with the raw JSON response. What might cause such an intermittent problem?

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Transfer/Receive?TransferID=" + $("#TransferID").val(),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {                    
            if (data.Message == "success") {
                $("#divTransferNo").dialog("destroy");

                $("#systemMsg").dialog({ autoOpen: true, title: "System Message", height: 150, modal: true });
                $("#systemMsg").html("<p>Transfer Received Successfully.</p>");
                $('div#systemMsg').bind('dialogclose', function (event) {
                    window.location = "../DrawMandrel/";
                });

            }
            else if(data.Message=="verifyreceiveback") {}
            else if (data.ErrorType == "validation") {
                $("#systemMsg").dialog({ autoOpen: true, title: "System Message", height: 150, modal: true });
                $("#systemMsg").html("<p>ERROR - This transfer has already been received.</p>");
            }
            else {                   
                $("#systemMsg").dialog({ autoOpen: true, title: "System Message", height: 150, modal: true });
                $("#systemMsg").html("<p>ERROR - Check your transfer number.</p>");
            }
        }            
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

I just received the response below which should have called:

```
else {                   
     $("#systemMsg").dialog({ autoOpen: true, title: "System Message", height: 150,   modal: true });
                $("#systemMsg").html("<p>ERROR - Check your transfer number.</p>");


{"Message":"ERROR: This transfer has already been  completed.","ErrorType":"validation","ErrorMessage":"ERROR: This transfer has already been completed.","OperationMessage":"ERROR: This transfer has already been completed.","BarCode":null}
```

UPDATE:

So I changed my ajax request to:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/Transfer/Receive?TransferID=" + $("#TransferID").val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            accept: {
                json: 'application/json',
                xml: 'application/xml'
            },
            success: function (data) {
```

And I am producing the following Request Headers:

[image]

Comment: The only line in your code that i see that could possible cause this is `window.location = "../DrawMandrel/";` unless your ajax call is possibly returning json encoded json.

Comment: What is your json raw response?

Comment: BABAL, please see my update above.

Comment: Just looked at my Request Headers.  I wonder if this is the problem ? Key Value
Accept text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*.  I'll try adding an accept array to the Ajax call.

Comment: How do I make the Accept header explicitly json ?